# RestClient GET pulling from data and an array

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, get, request

I am trying to pull data out of an API and am needing to get some out of an Array when i pull (or just get the whole array).

I am in C# asp.net Entity Framework

```
Date string 
IsPublicHoliday bool

Shifts = array  
    employeeId guid  
    startDate string 
    startTime string
    duration int
    unpaidBreaks int
    notes string
    roleId guid  
    Status byte 0 = Draft, 1 = Published, 2 = Confirmed, 3 = Queried 


Costs array 
    employeeId guid  
    date string In yyyy-MM-dd format 
    actual object  
        cost decimal  
        additionalCost decimal  
    estimated object  
        cost decimal  
        additionalCost decimal
```

So i need to pull in Date, Some from the shifts array and some from the costs Array.

My current class structure is:

```
public partial class RosterTime
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int SiteID { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int RosterTimesUniqueID { get; set; }

    public int RosterTime_Key { get; set; }

    public int Contacts_Key { get; set; }

    public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }

    public DateTime? EndTime { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan? Breaks { get; set; }

    public double? Hourly_Rate { get; set; }

    public string PayrollID { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Array Shifts { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Array Costs { get; set; }
```

And My request is as such:

```
public List<RosterTime> RosterData(string rosterId)
{
    var request = Request("roster-data/" + rosterId + "?startDate=" + DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "&endDate=" +
                            DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

    var result = _client.Execute<List<RosterTime>>(request);
    return result.Data;
}
```

How do i get the information out of those two arrays and save the data?

EDIT:
A shift class:

```
public class Shifts
{
    public Guid employeeId { get; set; }

    public string startDate { get; set; }

    public string startTime { get; set; }
    public int duration { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Once you have a collection of `RosterTime` access those properties. They could also be declared as collections, e.g. `public Shift[] Shifts` or `public IEnumerable<Shift> Shifts`. `Array` is not the collection type of array it's a class with static methods to manipulate arrays.

Comment: I have updated to public Shifts[] Shifts { get; set; } and am getting an error of System.MissingMethodException: 'No parameterless constructor defined for this object.' Edited original post showing the shift class

Comment: Ok did you modify `Costs` in the same way?

Comment: I hadn't touch costs yet but didnt think that would affect it

Comment: Well `Array` cannot be instantiated... So update that one too and if you still get the error then that will be pointing to `RosterTime`

Comment: Okay I have set up the Costs in the same way but am just stuck on this point when setting up costs: https://imgur.com/a/rV5dW. Thanks. Does Actual and Estimated need their own class aswell?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166426/discussion-between-jsteward-and-josh-fletcher).

Comment: Based on the discussion yesterday; the issue sounds like it's in your controller code. That would be specifically the code the uses EF to populate the bare `ReportTime` and collects that data needed to fill `Shifts` and `Costs`. The `RosterData` method does not seem to have any access to the information it would need to produce a fully formed `RosterTime`. On the server side once you have a bare `RosterTime` you'll need to either populate the `Shifts` and `Costs` manually or you can map them and use EF to populate those arrays through an  `.Include()`